# "Prediction interval" for a slope of a model fitted to new data

Tags: regression, cross-validation, prediction-interval

**Problem statement:**

I am using a simple linear regression with outcome $y$ and single predictor $x$ of the form:

$$
y_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma) \\
\mu_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i
$$

I assume fitting $\beta_0, \beta_1$ with maximum likelihoood (although if other method works better for the purpose of this question, I can use that). Then, I observe a new set of outcomes $\bar{y}$ for a (known) new set of predictors $\bar{x}$ which I assume come from the same process. I then assume a regression is fitted independently to $\bar{x}, \bar{y}$ obtaining $\bar{\beta}_0, \bar{\beta}_1$.

Is there an analytical way to use the original fit to get something like a "prediction interval" for $\bar\beta_1$? I am looking for an interval with the expected coverage properties for $\bar\beta_1$ - the *estimate* of the slope from $\bar{x}, \bar{y}$. I assume this is going to be noticeably wider than the confidence interval as there's the additional uncertainty arising from sampling $\bar{y}$ and constructing the estimate based on those samples.

I could obviously use simulations to obtain that interval, but I am curious if there is a more elegant way.

**Background:**

I am attempting to do something akin to cross validation for testing the extent that each of a set of possible summaries is "reproducible" - having $N$ replicates, intuitively, a summary is good, if summarising $N - K$ replicates of the experiment lets me predict the summary the remaining $K$ replicates well. One of the summaries I am experimenting with is a slope from a regression model, so I'd like to develop the expected prediction interval if the model was actually capturing the data well.

**Code example:**

The following code shows the problem and solution with simulations in R.

In each simulation, I am trying to use the linear fit to $x,y$ to construct an interval that would contain $\bar{\beta}_1$ in 95% of cases. I use the confidence interval and then I use simulations to construct a "prediction" interval.

```
x <- rep(0:5, times = 4)
xbar <- rep(0:5, times = 2)

N_sims <- 100

#Pre-allocate
y <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = N_sims, ncol = length(x))
ybar <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = N_sims, ncol = length(xbar))
b1 <- numeric(N_sims)
b1ci <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = N_sims, ncol = 2)
b1bar <- numeric(N_sims)

b1pred_sim <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = N_sims, ncol = 2)

for(i in 1:N_sims) {
  # Choose the true values randomly
  # The results are quite similar whether I choose
  # those separately for each simulation or 
  # once at the begining of the script
  true_b0 <- 1 + rnorm(1)
  true_b1 <- 0.5 + rnorm(1)
  true_sigma <- 1 + rlnorm(1)

  
  y_ <- rnorm(length(x), true_b0 + x * true_b1, sd = true_sigma)
  y[i,] <- y_
  fit <- lm(y_ ~ x)
  b1[i] <- coef(fit)["x"]
  b1ci[i,] <- confint(fit)["x",]
  
  ## Calculate the prediction interval with simulations
  N_inner_sims <- 1000
  sims_b1bar <- numeric(N_inner_sims)
  for(j in 1:N_inner_sims) {
    coef_sim_norm <- mvtnorm::rmvnorm(1, coef(fit), vcov(fit))
    # Transform to T distribution
    dof <- length(x) - 2
    coef_sim <- coef_sim_norm / sqrt(rchisq(2, dof) / dof)
    
    ysim <- rnorm(length(xbar), coef_sim[1] + xbar * coef_sim[2], sd = sigma(fit))
    fitsim <- lm(ysim ~ xbar)
    sims_b1bar[j] <- coef(fitsim)["xbar"]
  }
  b1pred_sim[i,] <- quantile(sims_b1bar, c(0.025,0.975))
  
  ## Actually fit the new data
  ybar_ <- rnorm(length(xbar), true_b0 + xbar * true_b1, sd = true_sigma)
  ybar[i,] <- ybar_
  fitbar <- lm(ybar_ ~ xbar)
  b1bar[i] <- coef(fitbar)["xbar"]
}

cat("Coverage CI: ", mean(b1bar >= b1ci[,1] & b1bar <= b1ci[,2]))
cat("Coverage prediction - sims: ", 
  mean(b1bar >= b1pred_sim[,1] & b1bar <= b1pred_sim[,2]))
```

Due to the simulations this is quite slow, but a typical result is something like:

```
Coverage CI:  0.81
Coverage prediction - sims:  0.96
```

so CI is too narrow while the simulations appear (at least approxiamtely) well calibrated. So the question is if I can get something like `b1pred_sim` analytically. Note that `b1pred_sim` is just appropriately widened CI:

[image]

Comment: Prediction intervals are usually meant for the intervals around predictions rather than parameters. What do you mean here? Aren't you interested in confidence intervals?

Comment: @Tim Agree that "prediction interval" might not be the best naming. The idea is this: I can make predictions for $\bar{y}$ given $\bar{x}$ - if my understanding of prediction intervals is correct, this is going the be a random vector of correlated t-distributed variables. I then should be able to transform predictions for $\bar{y}$ into predictions for some function of $\bar{y}$. $\bar{\beta}_1$ - the MLE of regression slope given $\bar{x}, \bar{y}$ is such a function. I want to construct a prediction interval for the value of this function. Does that clarify?

Comment: Could you give us an example illustrating the problem? It's not perfectly clear from your description.

Comment: @Tim I added a code example showing what I am after.

Comment: There's no reason for your simulation to work because you check if parameters from completely different models match confidence intervals from another model.

Comment: @Tim I agree confidence intervals shouldn't work here - but wanted to include them since you suggested that this might be what I am after. Note that the intervals I need (and approximate via simulations) are just somewhat widened CIs, so it is not like CIs are totally unrelated.... Note that both `fit` and `fitbar` share the same "true" values, so one _should_ provide some information about the other.

Comment: In what scenario you would have new data generated from an estimated model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142819/discussion-between-martin-modrak-and-tim).

Comment: Construct a pivotal quantity by dividing $\tilde\beta_1 - \hat\beta_1$ by its standard error.  This involves the $x_i$'s for the new unobserved data so these must be known. Replacing $\sigma$ in the denominator by its estimate $s$ based on the observed part of the data, the resulting quantity is $t$-distributed with $n-2$ degrees of freedom, where $n$ is the sample size of the observed data.

Comment: @JarleTufto indeed, this works. Expanded on that a bit and added as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Jarle Tufto](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/77222/jarle-tufto) who provided an outline of the main idea in the comments. All errors are my own.

We can realize that if $\sigma$ was known, the distribution of the MLE of the slope is $\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum (x_i - m)^2}$ where $m$ is the observed mean of $x$ (taken from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Normality_assumption) )

This means that the difference of the two MLEs is also going to be normally distributed. We however do not know $\sigma$, and plugging in the estimate of sigma from the first part, the resulting quantity is $t$-distributed with $n−2$ degrees of freedom, where $n$ is the sample size of the observed data.

So the prediction interval will be derived from t distribution centered at the MLE from the first batch of data and with standard error of $\sqrt{s^2 + \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sum (\bar{x}_i - \bar{m})^2}}$ where $\hat\sigma$ is the estimate of $\sigma$ from the first regression, $s$ is the standard error from the first regression and $\bar{m}$ is the mean of $\bar{x}$.

Adapting the code example from the question:

```
x <- rep(0:5, times = 4)
xbar <- rep(0:5, times = 2)

N_sims <- 10000

#Pre-allocate
y <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = N_sims, ncol = length(x))
ybar <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = N_sims, ncol = length(xbar))
b1 <- numeric(N_sims)
b1ci <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = N_sims, ncol = 2)
b1bar <- numeric(N_sims)

b1pred <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = N_sims, ncol = 2)

for(i in 1:N_sims) {
  # Choose the true values randomly
  # The results are quite similar whether I choose
  # those separately for each simulation or
  # once at the begining of the script
  true_b0 <- 1 + rnorm(1)
  true_b1 <- 0.5 + rnorm(1)
  true_sigma <- 1 + rlnorm(1)


  y_ <- rnorm(length(x), true_b0 + x * true_b1, sd = true_sigma)
  y[i,] <- y_
  fit <- lm(y_ ~ x)
  b1[i] <- coef(fit)["x"]
  b1ci[i,] <- confint(fit)["x",]

  # Calculate the prediction interval for b1bar
  b1bar_var <- sigma(fit)^2 / sum((xbar - mean(xbar))^2)
  b1_var <- vcov(fit)["x", "x"]
  diff_se <- sqrt(b1bar_var + b1_var)
  b1pred[i, ] <- b1[i] + qt(c(0.025,0.975), df = length(x) - 2) * diff_se

  ## Actually fit the new data
  ybar_ <- rnorm(length(xbar), true_b0 + xbar * true_b1, sd = true_sigma)
  ybar[i,] <- ybar_
  fitbar <- lm(ybar_ ~ xbar)
  b1bar[i] <- coef(fitbar)["xbar"]
}

cat("Coverage prediction: ", mean(b1bar >= b1pred[,1] & b1bar <= b1pred[,2]))
```

Shows the expected coverage behaviour.

Comment: I think there should be a square for $\hat{\sigma}$ under the square root in the equation for the standard error of the difference, right?

Comment: @COOLSerdash yes, thanks for noticing, fixed.